# Is P open /closed or both or neither?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\Bbb N\times \Bbb Q$ with the subspace topology of the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$ and  $P=\{(n,\dfrac{1}{n}):n\in \Bbb N\}$.

> Is P open /closed or both or neither?

Let $(k_n,\dfrac{1}{k_n})$ be a sequence in $P$ converging to $(a,b)$. Then $k_n\to a,\dfrac{1}{k_n}\to b\implies b=\dfrac{1}{a}\implies (a,b)\in P\implies P$ is closed.

If $P$ is open then each point is an interior point of $P$, consider $(k,\dfrac{1}{k})\in P\implies k\in \{k\};\dfrac{1}{k}\in (\dfrac{1}{k}-\epsilon,\dfrac{1}{k}+\epsilon)\cap \Bbb Q$; but $(\dfrac{1}{k}-\epsilon,\dfrac{1}{k}+\epsilon)\cap \Bbb Q\not\subset P$ (not subset of P).

Hence $P$ is not open

Please check my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arguments are correct. Another, perhaps slightly simpler, way to show that $P$ is closed is to note that if $\langle n,q\rangle\in X\setminus P$, and $\epsilon=\left|q-\frac1n\right|$, then $\{n\}\times(q-\epsilon,q+\epsilon)$ is an open nbhd of $\langle n,q\rangle$ in $X$ that is disjoint from $P$. Thus, $X\setminus P$ is open, and $P$ must be closed.

Using your sequence approach, you can also note that if $\langle k_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $a\in\Bbb N$, then there must be an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $k_n=a$ for each $n\ge m$. But then $\frac1{k_n}=\frac1a$ for each $n\ge m$, and it’s immediately obvious that your sequence converges to $\left\langle a,\frac1a\right\rangle$, since from some point on it’s constant at that point.

Comment: thank you sir;one more question **What will be boundary of $P$?**  ;Take any point $(k,\frac{1}{k})\in P$ then the open set $\{k\}\times (\frac{1}{k}-\epsilon ,\frac{1}{k}+\epsilon )\cap \Bbb Q$ does not contain points from both $P$ and $P^c$ and hence **Boundary of P=$\emptyset$**                    ;Is it right?

Comment: @Amartya: You're welcome. Yes, that's right.